# sourceBuffer.appendBuffer successfully but the h5 video player stuck

Tags: reactjs, express, html5-video, media-source

Here is my fontend code with React.js

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';

const VideoPage = () => {
  const videoInited = useRef(false)

  useEffect(() => {
    const video = document.querySelector("#stream-media-video") as HTMLMediaElement;

    // Using Bento4 to parse my mp4 video file
    // mp4info test.mp4 | grep Codec
    const mimeCodec = 'video/mp4; codecs="avc1.64081F, mp4a.40.2"';

    if ("MediaSource" in window && MediaSource.isTypeSupported(mimeCodec)) {
      const mediaSource = new MediaSource();
      video.src = URL.createObjectURL(mediaSource);
      mediaSource.addEventListener("sourceopen", sourceOpen);
    } else {
      console.error("Unsupported MIME type or codec: ", mimeCodec);
    }

    function sourceOpen(_) {
      console.log('[mediaSource sourceopen event trigger]: ', this.readyState); // open
      const mediaSource = this;

      const playBtn = document.querySelector('.play-btn');
      const init = () => {
        const sourceBuffer = mediaSource.addSourceBuffer(mimeCodec);

        // Get some video clips through xhr request (the video file is 1.5M in total, first get the first 1M part, and then get the next 0.5M part)
        fetchAB("/api/media/testmp4/part-v2?start=0&end=1000000", function (buf) {
          sourceBuffer.addEventListener('error', (e) => {
            console.error("sourceBuffer error", e);
          });
          
          sourceBuffer.addEventListener("updateend", function (_) {
            // mediaSource.endOfStream();

            video.play();
            videoInited.current = true;
            playBtn.removeEventListener("click", init);
  
          });
          sourceBuffer.appendBuffer(buf);

          // get the next 0.5M part
          fetchAB("/api/media/testmp4/part-v2?start=1000000&end=2000000", function (secondBuf){
            sourceBuffer.appendBuffer(secondBuf);
          });

        });
      }
      playBtn.addEventListener("click", init)

    }

    function fetchAB(url, cb) {
      const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.open("get", url);
      xhr.responseType = "arraybuffer";
      xhr.onload = function () {
        cb(xhr.response);
      };
      xhr.send();
    }

  }, [])

  const handleClickPlay = () => {
    const video = document.querySelector("video")
    if (videoInited.current) {
      video.play()
    }
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <video 
        id='stream-media-video'
        width="400px"
        height="400px"
        style={{
          objectFit: 'contain',
        }}
        controls
      />
      <div>
        <button className='play-btn' onClick={handleClickPlay}>click to play video</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default VideoPage
```

And Here is my backend code with Express.js

```
  app.get("/api/media/testmp4/part-v2", function (req, res) {
    const {
      start,
      end,
    } = req.query;
    const mp4FilePath = "test.mp4";
    const _start = Number(start);
    const videoSize = fs.statSync(mp4FilePath).size;
    const _end = Math.min(Number(end), videoSize - 1);

    // Get video clips and return them to the front end
    const videoStream = fs.createReadStream(mp4FilePath, { 
      start: _start, 
      end: _end,
    });

    videoStream.pipe(res);
  });
```

The progress bar in the video player shows that the remaining video clips have not been loaded and cannot continue to play. And here is my screenshot of problem.

[image]

There are no errors on the console, how can I make the video continue to play?

Comment: What's the byte size of your video file? Your URL includes a `start=0&end=1000000` which might be affecting how much bytes are returned to your app (as the requester)

Comment: The total size of my video files is 1500000 bytes. This should not be the reason, because I have controlled the returned file byte range on the server side `Math.min(Number(end), videoSize - 1)`. My guess is that it may be caused by the video media clip format.

Comment: _"My guess is that it may be caused by the video media clip format"_ Not true if the video plays ok when you're starting from zero bytes. The format issue(s) part will be known later when you try as: `start=1000000&end=1500000"` to try join some next bytes into back of the previous bytes (_eg:_ from the first: `0 - 1000000` reading). If you intend to play chunks then make sure the MP4 is segmented and saved as `.m4s` file format. Also M4S chunk files can be joined into one big file and renamed as `.mp4`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*"I have controlled the returned file byte range on the server side: 
 `Math.min(Number(end), videoSize - 1)`"*

Looking at:

```
const _end = Math.min(Number(end), videoSize - 1);
```

[Math.min](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/min) will return the **smallest one** from those two input numbers. 
Your `end` is smaller than `videoSize-1` so now it is being used as the limit of bytes returned back into your app for playback:

```
 var End  : 1000000
(Size-1)  : 1499999
file Size : 1500000
```

> *"The progress bar in the video player shows that the remaining video clip data has not been loaded and it cannot continue to play."*

To fix:

- Use the known file size (to get all data, with none remaining):

  fetchAB("/api/media/testmp4/part-v2?start=0&end=1500000");
- IF the file size is unknown, then use a very large number (true duration is the new MIN):

  fetchAB("/api/media/testmp4/part-v2?start=0&end=999999999999");

Comment: Thanks a lot, I got some ideas from it and solved the problem. What you said is not completely correct, because the file byte index starts from 0, and the last byte index is `videoSize - 1`, however `fs.createReadStream` read bytes from `start` to `end`, both the start index and the end index will be included! That means the first fetch should start from 0 to 1000000 bytes (total 1000001 bytes) and the second fetch should start from 1000001 to 1499999 bytes (all the remaining bytes). So I changed the second request parameters to `start=1000001&end=2000000` and successfully solved the problem.

Comment: Glad it's solved now and `+1` for fixing it yourself. So was it a _"numbers are off by 1"_ issue? PS: Is your video seekable in Chrome when you stream it like this?

Comment: Yes it was. PS: No, my video is unseekable. I just want to explore how video streaming works and will consider how to make the video seekable later.